# Adding a div with CSS to DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom

For a project, I am building an app that gets user input, stores it in an array, and displays the input in the DOM. I did the first two parts but I am having trouble displaying it. More specifically, I can't get the CSS to show up.

I have tried .createElement() which creates a new list-item but it does not include CSS. I am starting to think I am completely going about this incorrectly. If you need more information or code let me know.

```
\\HTML

<div id="boxhold">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <div class="twogrid">
    <h1>Fruit Juice</h1>
    <p>50</p>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

\\CSS

#boxhold {
margin: 0 auto;
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    li {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 408px;
        height: 75px;
        border: 3px solid $prime-color;
        h1 {
            font-family: $header-font;
            font-weight: $header-weight;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        p {
            font-family: $header-font;
            font-weight: $header-weight;
        }
    }
  }
}

\\JS
//Get Data

//Empty array for storing
var added = [];

//Get Data
var userInput = function() {
    return {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        amount: document.getElementById('amount').value
    }    
};


// Store Data
var newSugar = function(){
    return added.push(userInput());
}

// New HTML
function newBox() {
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');

    var newName = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var n = document.createTextNode(newName);
    newLi.appendChild(n);

    var newAmount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var a = document.createTextNode(newAmount);
    newLi.appendChild(a);

    var boxhold = document.getElementById('boxhold').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

    document.body.appendChild(newLi);    
};

//Adding stuff

 var displayData = (function() {

    var addInput = function() {
        var data = userInput();
        var item = newSugar();
        var box = newBox();
        //var box = newItem();
    };


    var addFood = document.getElementById('addFood');
    addFood.addEventListener('click', addInput);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
                addInput();
            }
        });    
})(userInput, newSugar, newBox);
```

Comment: Mind sharing what you have so far on the javascript side? Also, are you using a preprocessor for the css?

Comment: Oh, yes I am using Sass. And I will go ahead and add the rest of the JS in my post.

Comment: What preprocessor is that CSS? LESS?, SCSS,...? If it is something other than plain CSS, you need to render it into normal CSS, otherwise the browser will ignore it. If you aren't using a preprocessor then you better read up on CSS because it's invalid.

Comment: @nzart Please post the CSS after it's been rendered (ie normal CSS)

Comment: Do not add solutions to your question. Let me know if you remove that edit and I'll remove my downvote

Comment: @LGSon Why not? I'd want people to know that the solution was found? Mind you I'm still learning the ropes for StackOverflow so I don't know the etiquette.

Comment: The posted answers show the solution, and you accept the one that helped the most, and by that users here know which one you picked.

Comment: @LGSon Still don't understand but I'll remove it.

Comment: Then I suggest you read [ask] and [mcve] one more time. They explain the guidelines here at SO.

Comment: @LGSon Did not see that until I posted. Thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @nzart

It looks like you're appending the newly created list item to the document's body, which means it will be added as the last element of the page. Your CSS indicates that the styles only apply to list items inside of an unordered list, so this would explain the lack of styles.

The simple fix should be to replace `document.body.appendChild(newLi);` with `boxhold.appendChild(newLi);`.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Oliver! This worked! Now to just change some styling!

Comment: No problem, best of luck with the project!